# Restrict function param type to keys in object

Tags: typescript

How can I restrict my function parameter to be typed according to the keys of an object?
In order to have something like this:

```js
export const input = {
    a: {
        ROLE_a: 'xxx'
    },

    b: {
        ROLE_b: 'xxx'
    },

    c: {
        ROLE_c: 'xxx'
    }
};

export const doSomething = (param: ???) => {};

doSomething("dwdew"); // typing error
doSomething(input.a.ROLE_a) // success
```

Comment: You seem to want to limit where exactly it gets the value from, which isn't the goal of the type system. You could limit it to only allow `'xxx'`, but **not** to only use that value when it comes from `input`.

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mpDbbm) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please elaborate about what doesn't work for you (preferably by editing your code into a [mre] that shows the use case it doesn't satisfy).  Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

Actually, after reviewing the OP one more time, I see that this isn't *really* what's being asked for. The function isn't taking the whole object as the parameter, but instead a single nested value. As the comments on the question already indicate, the parameter can be typed to only be `xxx`, but not really to control *where* that comes from.

With that said, the original answer I posted may still have value to the OP or someone else:

## Original Answer

Assuming you expect the shape of that parameter to be the same always, you can just make a type or interface for that parameter:

```
interface Thing {
  a: {
    ROLE_a: string
  },
  b: {
    ROLE_b: string
  }
  // etc.
}

function doSomething(param: Thing) {
  // do something
  console.log(param.a.ROLE_a); // no error
}
```

Assuming you want a bit more flexibility, you can solve this with a combination of [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [template literal types + key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types)

```
type Things<Prefix extends string, Keys extends string> = {
    [K in Keys]: {
        [T in K as `${Prefix}_${K}`]: string
    }
};

type ParamsType = Things<'ROLE', 'a' | 'b'>

function doSomething(param: ParamsType) {
    // do something
    console.log(param.a.ROLE_a); // no error
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMDOAeACgJwgMwQA8oIjgIkATNKNYHZFAGigGkIRayLrb7GqAHxQAvFADeAKCiyoAbTZRk7TmgC6ALkky5e+TGVJ2UAIa0ABgBIJuAsQC+AfRtsHFrXQZNdsh1IcAbikpUEgoLFMcUwBbNBhwaHF4JkwAcgAlAHkAGQBRNNY00zSoAB8oNIAjNKEQ-ABXJABjYAQAe2MqdoBldpiIYERUAAowKNjtSOi4hMgASh09AHplqG66fsHhlF8oZs60doAbCAA6Y-aUMYmYs9Mz7PynU3nAqFWoJHbSHBx2nABIA)